# Struts 1.3 Error messages displaying improperly on jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

Currently I'm getting ???en_US.error:??? displayed on the jsp page when the error is thrown from Action class-

### Here is where I add the error message:

```
ActionMessages msg = new ActionMessages();
msg.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage(e.getMessage()));
saveErrors(request, msg);
e.printStackTrace();
return (new ActionForward(mapping.findForward("failure")));
```

### And in JSP I have -

```
<logic:messagesPresent>
    <html:messages id="message"><br/>
        <span style="color:red"><bean:write name="message"/></span><br/><br/>
    </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

### Struts Mapping:

```
<action path="/paymentsEdit" type="com.pncbank.capmkts.payments.ui.PaymentsEditAction" 
                name="paymentsEditForm" scope="request">
<forward name="edit" path="/payments/paymentsEdit.jsp" />
<forward name="failure" path="/payments/paymentsDashboard.jsp" />
<forward name="history" path="/payments/paymentsEditHistory.jsp" />
</action>
```

### Message displayed on JSP page

???en_US.ERROR: Unable to load Net Payment. ???

How to get rid of **???en_US.** and **???** from error message.

Comment: Can you share the mapping for this `mapping.findForward("failure")`?

Comment: Here it is- <action path="/paymentsEdit" type="com.pncbank.capmkts.payments.ui.PaymentsEditAction" 
    name="paymentsEditForm" scope="request">
   <forward name="edit" path="/payments/paymentsEdit.jsp" />
   <forward name="failure" path="/payments/paymentsDashboard.jsp" />
   <forward name="history" path="/payments/paymentsEditHistory.jsp" />
  </action>

Comment: please update your question with the above content, it will be better

Comment: Do you have a message property file for English?

Comment: No, I don't have one in the project. Is it required?

Comment: The `???` part means it's expected a message resource and there isn't a matching key. A tutorial like [this one](http://www.laliluna.com/articles/posts/struts-message-resources-tutorial.html) might help; tbh I barely remember how the S1 messages work.

Comment: It seem that you are missing the ressources properties files. 
Be sure you have your MessageResources_en.properties or MessageResources_en_US.properties.

You can use <bean:message key="web.login.error"/> instead of <bean:write name="message"/>